# Conditional copy and paste

Tags: excel, copy, copy-paste, paste, vba

In Excel I have two worksheets.

The first lists my comments on a Word file each with a code (in the form ABC and a number), a comment, and other information.

Another links these codes to a comment in Word. This has been collected using a macro, which returns the page number of each of the word Comments (which is stored in the second column).

I now want to copy the page numbers into the original worksheet.

My problem is that the two sets of data are not commensurable, so the data can not be simply pasted. Thus ref. A104 in the first worksheet has a page reference (15) in the second workbook, but A105 does not. Also, some references (A106) for instance have multiple page references so occur multiple times in the second workbook but only once in the first.

In the first worksheet, col. A contains the references, and col. F is where I want to paste the page numbers (the other columns contain various other data).

In the second worksheet, the data in col. A corresponds to the refs. in Sheet1:column A, and col. B contains the page references.

In short, I want to copy data from sheet 2:col.B into sheet1:colF only where Sheet 1:col. A corresponds to sheet 2:col A. Is this possible?

Comment: Post the code you've come up with and highlight the part that's not working, we'll be happy to help from there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. This is not difficult. You could do it too, or at least try to. That's what we value here - seeing efforts. So next time, please, show some effort first and post your code when you actually have a real coding issue.

In your case, I assumed that your sheets are named "Sheet1" and Sheet2".

Don't forget to check the checkmark if the answer is helpful. And please read our [Tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

```
Sub ttt()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim str As String

For i = 1 To ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If ws1.Range("A" & i).Value = ws2.Range("A" & j).Value Then
            str = str & ws2.Range("B" & j).Value & ", "
        End If
    Next
    If Len(str) > 1 Then
        str = Left(str, Len(str) - 2)
        ws1.Range("F" & i).Value = str
    End If
    str = vbNullString
Next

End Sub
```